# Wait for file to delete, then copy a folder

Tags: loops, powershell, while-loop, wait, delete-file

I have a couple of scripts that have to sync a folder from the network server, to the local terminal server, and lastly into the %LOCALAPPDATA%. I need to first check if a folder is being synced (this is done by creating a temporary COPYING.TXT on the server), and wait until that is removed, THEN copy to %LOCALAPPDATA%.

Something like this:

- Server-side script executes, which syncs my folder to all of my terminal servers.
- It creates a COPYING.TXT temporary file, which indicates the sync is in progress. Once the sync is finished, the script removes the COPYING.TXT
- If someone logs on during the sync, I need a script to wait until the COPYING.TXT is deleted I.E the sync is finished, then resume the local sync into their %LOCALAPPDATA%.

```
do {
  cp c:\folder\program $env:LOCALAPPDATA\
} while ( !(test-path c:\folder\COPYING.txt) )
```

(So that copies the folder while the file DOESN'T exist, but I don't think that exits cleanly)

Or:

```
while ( !(test-path c:\folder\COPYING.txt) ) {
  cp c:\folder\program $env:LOCALAPPDATA\ -recurse -force
  if ( !(test-path c:\folder\program) ) {return} 
}
```

But that script quits if the COPYING.TXT exists. I think I need to create a function and insert that function within itself, or a nested while loop, but that is starting to make my head hurt.

Comment: @user3317623 I had some time for a cold-press coffee and a good think and I found a solution, however I cannot answer my own question :(.

Comment: function task {
while(test-path c:\folder\COPYING.txt){sleep -seconds 1}
cp c:\folder\program $env:LOCALAPPDATA\ -recurse -force
exit
}
task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a try to use c# FileSystemWatcher, to monitor the target folder, when change event raised, then check the target file, if it no exits, your expected time is comming： do it.

Answer (score 1):

As Mosser Lee said, try using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Here is a working sample.

```
#Create the Copying.txt file
"test"|Out-File Copying.txt
#Create a filesystemwatcher
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
#Give it the root path to monitor
$watcher.Path = $pwd
#The matching pattern
$watcher.Filter = "Copying.txt"
#Monitor subfolder or not
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
#Setup event and save a ref
$evt = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Deleted FileDeleted -Action {
    #Stuff it into the global space just so you can inspect it
    $global:SomeVar = $Event
    Write-Host ("{0} deleted at {1}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath, $Event.TimeGenerated)
}

Remove-Item Copying.txt
```

This gives output like "H:\Copying.txt deleted at 6/12/2014 3:01:48 PM" when the file is deleted. It also sets a global variable $global:SomeVar if you wanted to look at the properties in depth.

```
$global:SomeVar

ComputerName     :
RunspaceId       : 1ab5089e-1734-4b92-8bab-9de4df78ada2
EventIdentifier  : 2
Sender           : System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
SourceEventArgs  : System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs
SourceArgs       : {System.IO.FileSystemWatcher, Copying.txt}
SourceIdentifier : FileDeleted
TimeGenerated    : 6/12/2014 3:01:48 PM
MessageData      :
```

Don't forget to unregister the event as it will continue to run until you close the session even if you set $watcher to null.

```
Unregister-Event $evt.Id
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the post, I accepted it as an answer but I cannot "upvote" your post because I need 15 reputations. Thanks again for your post. Cheers.